# Convergence of $\sum\frac{|\cos n|}{n\log n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I wonder if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|\cos n|}{n\log n}$$ converges.

I tried to applying the condensation test, getting $$\sum\frac{2^n|\cos 2^n|}{2^n\log{2^n}}=\sum\frac{|\cos 2^n|}{n\log 2}$$ but I don't know how to show it converges?

Am I in the right way?

Comment: Convergence cannot be proved, since the series diverges,

Comment: Be careful with the limits of summation. also have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574503/infinite-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-log-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$|\cos n| \geqslant \cos^2 n = \frac1{2} + \frac1{2}\cos(2n).$$

Hence

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{|\cos k|}{k \log k}\geqslant \frac1{2}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k \log k}+\frac1{2}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{\cos(2k)}{k \log k}.$$

The series on the LHS diverges because the first sum on the RHS diverges by the integral test and the second sum converges by Dirichlet's test.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that
the sum diverges since
the average value of
$|\cos(n)|$
is around
$\frac12$
and 
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac1{n \log n}$
diverges.

A proof could probably be made rigorous
by noting that,
if $|\cos n|$ is small,
then
$n$ is close to
$\pi(k+\frac12)$
for some integer $k$,
so that
$|\cos(n-1)|$
and
$|\cos(n+1)|$
would be bounded
away from zero
so that the sum of the
three terms for
$n-1, n, n+1$
would be
greater than
some multiple
(about, say, 2/3 or 1/2)
of the corresponding sum
for $\frac1{n \log n}$.