# What can be said about the convergence of this series?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What can be said about the convergence of the following modification of the *hyperharmonic series* ($\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}}$, which is convergent for any s>1):
$$\sum \frac{1}{n^{s_n}}$$ with $s_n$ strictly monotonically approaching 1 from above? In case both convergence and divergence are still possible under this condition, is it possible to give a specific criteria for convergence, e.g. in terms of the rate of convergence of $s_n$?

Comment: It certainly might not converge. For example $s_n=\log_n(n+1)$.

Comment: So the question is, can you make $s_n$ converge slowly enough to $1$ to make it converge.

Comment: Yes, this is the question which is left over, after that on-spot counterexample!

Comment: I mean, there are cases of $s_n$ where the series doesn't converge. Probably "certainly" and "might" shouldn't be in the same sentence, ever. :)

Comment: $s_n = \frac{log(n) + 1}{log(n)}$ would be quite slow already. Not sure if this converges.

Comment: Nope, $\frac{\log(n)+1}{\log(n)} = 1+\log_n(e)$ so $n^{s_n}=en$, and $\sum\frac{1}{en}$ does not converge.

Comment: Nope! $$1/n^{\frac{\log n +1}{\log n}} = 1/en$$
whose sum diverges. You could use 
$$s_n = \frac{\log{(n\log^2 n)}}{\log n}$$
This gives us
$$\sum \frac{1}{n\log^2 n} $$
which converges

Comment: So thats great! So all in all it means it really does depend on how fast $s_n$ converges to 1.

Comment: Would it be possible to quantify the required convergence rate exactly for obtaining a sharp criteria?

Comment: I see that for $s_n = \frac{log(n\;log(n))}{log\; n}$ it diverges (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574503/infinite-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-log-n). But we can put some $s_n = \frac{log(n\; f(n))}{log\; n}$ here, say $n^\epsilon$.

Comment: Im mean we can put there some $f(n)$ in. And this choice gives $s_n = 1 + \epsilon$, when I'm not mistaken, thus is not monotonically converging to 1.

Comment: There are no sharp boundaries in convergence. You just stare at some $f(n)$ (here or elsewhere) and wonder how fast it might grow, then you check $f(n)=n^s$ and find (say) that $s\le1$, then you throw in some slower-growing function, so now $f(n)=n\cdot\log^r n$, then you find the critical value for $r$, then it turns out that you may add some of $\log\log n$, and so it goes.

Comment: Ivan Neretin: Can this process then not be understood as a kind of nested intervals - which would give rise to the existence of some unique entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the specific choice of the sequence $s_n$, for $n\rightarrow\infty$ both convergence, i.e. for  $$s_n = \frac{log(n\;log^2 n)}{log\;n} \rightarrow 1^+$$ resulting in $$\sum \frac{1}{n\;log^2 n} \rightarrow c \lt \infty;$$ or divengence, i.e. for $$s_n = log_n(n+1) \rightarrow 1^+$$ resulting in $$\sum \frac{1}{n+1} \rightarrow \infty $$ is possible.