# Sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2e^{{-(\log n)}^{1+\delta}}$ for some $\delta > 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2e^{{-(\log n)}^{1+\delta}}$$ convergent for some $\delta > 0$?

I tried to do it by comparison test but it was not doable. I tried to take help from [Infinite series $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n \log (n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574503/infinite-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-log-n). I was unable to proceed further. What I have got is that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2e^{{-(\log n)}^{1+\delta}} = 0$$ for any $\delta >0$.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: $e^{2\log n-(\log n)^{1+\delta}} \le e^{-(\log n)^{1+\frac{\delta}{2}}} \le e^{-2\log n} = n^{-2}$ for large $n$

Comment: Wow. Thank you @mathworker21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does converge for some $\delta>0$. Here is an example.
I assume that by $\log$ you mean natural logarithm.
Note that $e^{-(\log n)^{1+\delta}}=e^{-(\log \,n)(\log\,n)^\delta}=n^{-(\log \,n)^\delta}$. Then your series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2-(\log \,n)^\delta}$. Take $\delta=1$. Since $(\log\,20)-2<1$ and $(\log\,21)-2>1$ we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2-\log \,n}
=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^{(\log \,n)-2}}
=
\sum_{n=1}^{21} {1\over n^{(\log \,n)-2}}
+
\sum_{n=22}^\infty {1\over n^{(\log \,n)-2}}
$$
$$
\le 
\sum_{n=1}^{21} {1\over n^{(\log \,n)-2}}
+
\sum_{n=22}^\infty {1\over n^{(\log \,22)-2}} < \infty.
$$
The last series converges because $\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{-\alpha}$ converges if $\alpha>1$.

Comment: how is $e^{-(\log \,n)(\log\,n)^\delta}=n^{-(\log \,n)^\delta}$?

Comment: $e^{-(\log \,n)(\log\,n)^\delta}=[exp(\log \,n)]^{-(\log\,n)^\delta}=n^{-(\log \,n)^\delta}$