# How to find a real sequence $x_n$ such that $n x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm stuck on trying to find a real sequence $x_n$ such that $n x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ diverges. Here's what I have tried so far:

I've started with trying to find $x_n$ as a real-valued function of $n$. In order to have $n x_n \to 0$, we require $$\frac{x_n}{1/n} \to 0$$ and since the denominator tends to $0$ as $n$ increases, we require that $x_n \to 0$. We also require that $x_n$ tends to $0$ "faster" than $1/n$ does, in order for the above quotient to go to $0$.

However if you try functions such as $x_n=1/n^2$ or $x_n=n/2^n$ (for example) which tend to $0$ faster than $1/n$ does, then you see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ converges and I haven't been able to find a function for $x_n$ that satisfies the above conditions and also has a divergent infinite sum. It's certainly possible that the form for $x_n$ might not be a simple elementary function of $n$, but I don't know how you'd go about finding any "unusual constructions" that work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $x_n = \dfrac 1 {n\ln n }.$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574503/infinite-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-log-n

Comment: Thanks, may I ask if there's any particular approach to finding such a function?

Comment: @Integral12 We want something smaller than $1/n$ but bigger than $1/n^2$, so $1/(n \ln{n})$ is a good idea.

Comment: More specifically: the _p-series_ $\sum_n\frac1{n^p}$ is known to converge for $p\gt 1$, so if you write $x_n=\frac1{nr_n}$, whatever sequence you take for $r_n$ will have to grow slower than $n^\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$. The logarithm is then the first natural candidate.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way that you might plausibly come to an answer like $x_n=\frac1{n\log n}$: We know that $\sum_{i\lt n}\frac1i\approx\log n$. If we want a divergent series, then the partial sums of our series will still need to go to infinity, but they'll need to do it at an even slower rate than $\log n$. We could try a couple of natural targets for our partial sums, say $\sqrt{\log n}$ or $\log\log n$.

But how do we get a term $x_n$ that gives us partial sums that grow this way? This is where the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) comes in handy: we know that we can approximate $\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$ by $\int_1^n f(x)\ dx$, and vice versa. So we want a function $f()$ with $\int_{1}^n f(x)\ dx\approx\sqrt{\log n}$. How do we find one?

Well, we turn to another tool: the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus! Since the integral is the antiderivative, we can start with our target function $g(n)=\sqrt{\log n}$, say, and take the derivative $f(x)=\frac{dg}{dx}$ of this; by the chain rule we get $f(x)=\frac1{2x\sqrt{\log(x)}}$. The constant factor of 2 doesn't matter for convergence here, so we can multiply it away; we get that $x_n=\frac1{n\sqrt{\log n}}$ will yield a divergent series because $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\approx C\sqrt{\log n}$ for some constant $C$. At the same time, by the way we constructed our sequence as diverging 'more slowly' to infinity than $\log n$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n\to 0$ (as you can see for yourself). Doing the same with $g(n)=\log\log n$ will give you the suggested $x_n=\frac1{n\log n}$ term.

You sometimes need to be a little careful going back and forth between sums and integrals like this, but for general questions of convergence and approximation it's one of the most useful tools in the toolbox.

Comment: How come this answer didn't get a single upvote till now? I'd upvote this a few more times if I could! This answer provides motivation and insight into how one would systematically come up with a counterexample. +1 :)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I didn't get this together until after the previous answer had been accepted, and a lot of folks don't really look at questions with accepted answers; that said, I am of course grateful for the 'support' and very glad that this answer is appreciated!